# Query about MySql behaviour

Tags: mysql, database

I would like to know about a behavior of MySql. Like,I need to search a piece of information from a table from Last one month records where I have records of several years in that table. In this regard What MySql will do?? Will MySql search in the whole table among the records of several years ??

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any indexing/partitioning on your table?

Comment: What will MySql do if I have index or I have not index ??

Comment: already answered! :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the table structure and the type of query used to fetch the data..

If you are using indexes on the date column that you are using in the where clause then MySQL will search the data only from last month rows, otherwise MySQL needs to scan whole table.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How does indexing prevent MySql to scan whole table?? I think MySql will traverse the date column of whole table.

Comment: no it will create separate index pages and fetch the only relevant data according to dates matched

Answer (score 0):

If you have any indexing/partitioning done on that column, then it will search only a specific area of your table, and not the whole table. 
 But if you have not used any optimization technique like indexing or partitioning, then it will search the whole table.